# How to make GraphQL enum data in resolver with nestjs/graphql?

Tags: enums, graphql, nestjs

In this way, it can pass enum data in resolver:

```js
    enum AuthType {
     GOOGLE =  'google-auth',
     GITHUB =  'github-auth',
     OUTLOOK = 'outlook-auth',
    }

    interface UsersArgs {
      first: number,
      from?: string,
      status?: String,
      authType?: AuthType,
    }

    export const resolvers = {
      AuthType,
      Query: {
        users: (_record: never, args: UsersArgs, _context: never) {
          // args.authType will always be 'google-auth' or  'github-auth' or 'outlook-auth'
          // ...
        }
      }
    }
```

There is also good example for pure GraphQL syntax as:

https://www.graphql-tools.com/docs/scalars#internal-values

In NestJS, the code like

```js
    import { Args, Query, Resolver } from '@nestjs/graphql';

    import { AuthType } from '@enum/authEnum';

    @Resolver()
    export class AuthResolver {
      constructor(private readonly authRepo: AbstractAuthSettingRepository) {}
      
      @Query(() => AuthSetting)
      findAuth(
        @Args('input')
        id: string,
      ): Promise<AuthSetting | undefined> {
        return this.authRepo.findOne({ id });
      }
    }
```

How can I use `AuthType` in the `AuthResolver` class?

Comment: The question is absolutely unclear, the two code snippets do two totally different things. There's one thing missing in your NestJS code for sure, I'll add an an answer for that though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to use enums in NestJS GraphQL, you need to register them once:

```js
import { registerEnumType } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { AuthType } from '@enum/authEnum';

registerEnumType(AuthType, { name: 'AuthType' });
```